# How to implement a Kayak-style country/currency dropdown using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, internationalization

Is there a jQuery plugin that approximates the functionality of the country/currency dropdown on [the Kayak homepage](http://www.kayak.com/)?

I need to do something similar on my own site and don't want to reinvent the wheel if possible.

Comment: I can't imagine anyone writing a plugin for something so simple.  You simply create a DIV with the appropriate country/currency links, then use show/hide or any number of animation options to toggle it.  You would probably spend more time customizing the markup and CSS of a plugin than just doing it yourself.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a source of information mapping currencies to countries? If so please clarify the question as such because it seems people are reading this that you're asking about just the GUI implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Example (it seriously can be done in many variations)

```
<style>
    #currencyLink { position: relative; } // we make anchor for the absolutely positioned #currencyList
    #currencyList { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px } // you may need to tweak these values
</style>

<div id="header">
     <div id="currencyLink"><span onclick=" $('#currencyList').toggle(); ">Show currencies</span>
         <div id="currencyList">
              <a href="#">Currency 1</a>
              <a href="#">Currency 2</a>
              <a href="#">Currency 3</a>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```